# Too many values to unpack (expected 2) python django tastypie

Tags: python, django, dictionary, tastypie

Here is my dict:

```
{'interno__exact': False, 'formulario__protocolo__id__exact': '5', 'autor__funcionario__funcao__id__exact': '2'}
```

I'm getting this error:

`too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

on this execution:

```
count = Avaliacao.objects.filter( applicable_filters )
```

Does someone know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your line of code is quite long! If you split it in several steps, it may be easier to identify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it, just change from:

```
count = Avaliacao.objects.filter( applicable_filters )
```

to:

```
count = Avaliacao.objects.filter( **applicable_filters )
```

Answer (score 0):

too many values too unpack means that you have to have equal amounts of values on each side of the equal sign, watch this:

```
a,b = 1,2
```

then a would equal 1 and b would equal 2.
you need to have an equal amount of things to unpack and thing to make them mean.

if i type in:

```
print(a)
print(b)
```

it would say

```
1
2
```